# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured. Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm facing the issue like
1.java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
2.org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:57194/devtools/browser/b136f808-5024-4a5a-be83-250fced8667a
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'

Chrome version is111.0.5563.65 so installed the chrome driver 111.0.5563.64 https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKnmz.png)
Could anyone please help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc5sm.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's [Selenium bug 11750](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins/c/DOJ65WfxcXs/m/N5Ba1sHgAgAJ), the options are in:

1. Add `--remote-allow-origins=*` option to the "Options" tab of your [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/)

   [image]
2. Downgrade [Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/) and [Chromedriver to version 110](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=110.0.5481.77/)
3. Upgrade to the latest version of the WebDriver Sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager), it will pick up new Selenium java client dependencies containing the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I am using openjdk 1.8 and apache jmeter 5.5 with the webdriver support plugin on version 4.8.1.

Followed the tutorials with the basic driver config and the sampler. It also said in the Error log earlier, that it only suports chrome version 112.

I downloaded that version from the chrome beta program and configured the Chrome driver config (options) to adress both problems.

Binary: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe
Additional arguments: --remote-allow-origins=* (i got from a selenium problem thread)

Comment: Hi Florian, Thanks for the update. Downloaded chrome beta as per your suggestion. Could you please tell me what is binary and next steps to do with binary please?

Comment: I am by no means an expert. But first, there are 2 binaries here, the main chrome executable and the driver that controlls it. The one you mean is the actual google chrome program and it has this static link. Keep in mind this is a temporary solution. Here is some context where i used it: [image](https://ibb.co/m80ygx1)
[image2](https://ibb.co/T1YcX2f) Hope it gets fixed soon, or it did already? I recommend using plain selenium.

Comment: Also, as the other guy already said, your problem did likely only need the "Additional arguments" fix, and i also recommend using the 110 or 111 drivers.