# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured for chrome version 117.0.5938.11

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver

Today Google chrome version has been upgraded and version is 117.0.5938.11 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) so downloaded the Chrome driver beta  Version: 117.0.5938.11 (r1181205) and when I click on Run Button in Jmeter, chrome browser is not invoking and after 1minute getting as Browser not configured.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XIHE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHRNh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2xlw.png)

Could anyone please help me

Comment: you might check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75790752/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-browser-has-not-been-configured-please-ensu

Answer (score 0):

Partial log doesn't tell the full story, scroll up to see the real cause of the error

If it is not there - [enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) and also check [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))/[stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) for any suspicious entries.